# JOOQ fetch record from table and insert it into another table

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to select all fields from one table, fetch into a record of another table, and insert the record into that table. However, I am getting an error saying that the values are null. Here is the relevant piece of code:

```java
    // Fetch
    PersonDeactivatedRecord person = getContext().selectFrom(PERSON)
            .where(PERSON.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOneInto(PersonDeactivatedRecord.class);

    // Insert
    person.setDeactivatedOn(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    getContext().insertInto(PERSON_DEACTIVATED)
            .set(person)
            .execute();
```

The `person_deactivated` table is a copy of `person` table plus one more column (deactivated_on). The error I'm getting is this:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "xxx"."person_deactivated" ("deactivated_on") values (cast(? as timestamp))]; ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ...)
```

Note that when I debug this code I see that `person` object is fully populated as expected. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`InsertSetStep.set(Record)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertSetStep.html#set-org.jooq.Record-) method will not insert the entire `person` record into the target table, but consider only those fields whose value is "changed". See the Javadoc:

> This is the same as calling [`set(Map)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertSetStep.html#set-java.util.Map-) with the argument record treated as a `Map<Field<?>, Object>`, except that the [`Record.changed()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed--) flags are taken into consideration in order to update only changed values.

So, you have several possibilities to fix this issue (there are more than the ones I list here, of course):

#### 1. Set all changed flags to true

This will be the simplest fix:

```java
// Insert
person.setDeactivatedOn(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
person.changed(true); // Sets all flags to true
getContext().insertInto(PERSON_DEACTIVATED)
        .set(person)
        .execute();
```

#### 2. Write a single query

The advantage of this solution is that you have only a single query, which means:

1. A single server roundtrip (less latency)
2. Better locking semantics (the database knows what you're doing, so there are less chances of race conditions)

So, you could write:

```java
getContext()
    .insertInto(PERSON_DEACTIVATED)
    .columns(PERSON_DEACTIVATED.fields())
    .select(
        select(Arrays
           .stream(PERSON_DEACTIVATED.fields())
           .map(f -> f.equals(PERSON_DEACTIVATED.DEACTIVATED_ON)
                   ? currentTimestamp()
                   : PERSON.field(f))
           .collect(Collectors.toList()))
       .from(PERSON)
       .where(PERSON.ID.eq(id))
    )
    .execute();
```

As always, this answer assumes you have the following static import in your code:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

The above query will insert all columns from `PERSON` into `PERSON_DEACTIVATED`, except the `DEACTIVATED_ON` column will be replaced by the current timestamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I went with the first solution (since it's more readable for me and user deactivation won't happen very often so I can ignore the advantages of the second solution) and it works! Note that there is a minor problem with the second solution as PERSON doesn't have a DEACTIVATED_ON column (it exists only in the other table).

Comment: @Egemen: OK, thanks for the feedback. I fixed the second solution. It's probably better this way anyway, as it won't depend on the order of columns.

Comment: @LukasEder for solution 2, the inner select method is not found in the JOOQ library, e.g. does not compile.  I checked the various `DSL.select` variations.

Comment: @JoseMartinez: 1) I'm assuming you have the static import, which I've just added to the answer, in place. 2) what error are you getting? More specifically, since you probably didn't write the exact same query, would you mind asking a new question with the actual query you've written and/or suggest a fix to my answer?