# jOOQ - How to refer to the value of a field in a query

Tags: sql, jooq

I have a DB table with information about a release. A release has a minor version number which is an integer. I want to execute a query that reads the values from a given release and returns the current value for all the fields in the table (minus the ID), and the minor version increased by one.

The query below returns the current value, but I can't figure out how I can take the current value and increase it by one.

```
select(Arrays
    .stream(V_RELEASE.fields())
    .filter(f -> !f.equals(V_RELEASE.ID))
    .map(f -> f.equals(V_RELEASE.MINOR_VERSION)
        ? V_RELEASE.MINOR_VERSION   <-- I want to increase this by 1
        : V_RELEASE.field(f))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .from(V_RELEASE)
    .where(V_RELEASE.ID.eq(id))
```

I am sure this has a very simple solution, but I have been banging my head against the wall for a a few hours now to no avail. Can anyone help out a jOOQ newbie with the correct syntax?

**Added context**:
I am basing my query on the reply to the following question:

[JOOQ fetch record from table and insert it into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618843/jooq-fetch-record-from-table-and-insert-it-into-another-table)

The complete query is supposed to create a new record based on an existing one with the minor version increased by 1, and looks like this:

```
ctx
    .insertInto(V_RELEASE)
    .columns(Arrays.stream(V_RELEASE.fields())
        .filter(f -> !f.equals(V_RELEASE.ID))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .select(
        select(Arrays
            .stream(V_RELEASE.fields())
            .filter(f -> !f.equals(V_RELEASE.ID))
            .map(f -> f.equals(V_RELEASE.MINOR_VERSION)
                  // I want to increase the minor version number by 1
                ? V_RELEASE.MINOR_VERSION 

                : V_RELEASE.field(f))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .from(V_RELEASE)
            .where(V_RELEASE.ID.eq(id))
    )
    .execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a bit of RTFMing later I found that the answer was beautifully simple. jOOQ has support for [arithmetic functions on columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/arithmetic-expressions/), so I could just call .add(1) on the column to get to where I wanted:

```
select(Arrays
    .stream(V_RELEASE.fields())
    .filter(f -> !f.equals(V_RELEASE.ID))
    .map(f -> f.equals(V_RELEASE.MINOR_VERSION)
        ? V_RELEASE.MINOR_VERSION.add(1)
        : V_RELEASE.field(f))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .from(V_RELEASE)
    .where(V_RELEASE.ID.eq(id))
```